# Remover margin com jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Numa dada página, ao abrir, preciso de remover a `margin` da classe `content`  para ficar como pretendo.

CSS:

```
.three-columns .content {
    margin: 20px 250px 0 250px;
}

.content {
    margin: 20px 0 0 250px;
}
```

Estou a tentar ir por `jquery` ao fazer:

```
$("#three-columns:content").css({ 'margin': ' 10px 10px 10px 10px' }); //Sei que o erro está aqui
$("#content").css({ 'margin': ' 10px 10px 10px 10px' });
```

O que pretendo é remover/alterar a `margin` de `.three-columns .content` e `.content`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parece-me que está a definir o alvo da ação a realizar pelo jQuery de forma errada.

No teu CSS tens:

```
.three-columns .content { ... }
.content { ... }
```

Para atingires o mesmo elemento via jQuery tens que usar o mesmo selector:

```
$(".three-columns .content").css({
    'margin' : '10px 10px 10px 10px'
});

$(".content").css({
    'margin' : '10px 10px 10px 10px'
});
```

---

Por outro lado, parece que estás a repetir o código, visto que se queres alterar a `margin` do elemento com a classe de CSS `content`, basta uma linha:

```
$(".content").css({
    'margin' : '10px 10px 10px 10px'
});
```

Mas se existe algo mais que não está a apresentar na pergunta, podes também usar uma só linha para definir o mesmo estilo para ambos os elementos fazendo uso da separação de selectores:

```
$(".three-columns .content, .content").css({
    'margin' : '10px 10px 10px 10px'
});
```

---

Se quiseres simplificar, dado o valor da margem ser igual para o topo, direita, fundo e esquerda, podes usar:

```
$(".three-columns .content, .content").css({
    'margin' : '10px'
});
```

Comment: É isto mesmo, obrigado!

Answer (score 6):

Você esta utilizando o símbolo `#`, que seleciona elementos pelo seu atributo `id`. Utilize um ponto ao invés desse caractere, e você obterá os elementos que possuírem aquela classe.

Ficaria assim:

```
$(".three-columns .content").css('margin', ' 10px 10px 10px 10px');
$(".content").css('margin', ' 10px 10px 10px 10px');
```

O mesmo vale para o CSS. Se quiser aplicar determinada formatação, via CSS, a elementos que contenham um `id` específico, utilize o caractere `#` ao invés do ponto.

Comment: Não esta a resultar. Se eu comentar ambas as propriedades no ficheiro do css, o layout fica como quero. Agora a alterar não está a resultar

Comment: Fiz uma pequena alteração no código, para passar múltiplos parâmetros ao invés de um objecto em cada chamada do método `css` do jQuery. Peço que tente novamente, utilizando essa forma.

Comment: Já sei onde está o problema no seu código (onde tive de alterar para funcionar, possivelmente funciona noutros casos):
`".three-columns:content"` para `".three-columns .content"`

Comment: Ok, alterei novamente para refletir isso. Mas confesso que gostei mais da resposta do Zuul :)

Comment: Sim, vou colocar voto na sua reposta mas resposta aceite na dele. Obrigado ;)

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $(".content").css('margin','10px');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Isto funcionava no caso de não ter uma classe a partir de outra, ou seja, se `.three-columns .content` não existisse.